# Excel VBA Columns in chart - format font, color, alignment etc

Tags: vba, excel

I am having troubles formatting columns in a chart to match a specific font, colour, alignment etc.

This code, while focused on column A:A, it applies to every single cell in the worksheet. I only want it to affect Column A:

```
Sub PGMNumber()
'
' PGMNumber Macro
'

'
    Range("A:A").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -10477568
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 9.43
End Sub
```

This was done by recording my steps. All I need is FontName, Colour, Bold, Size and Alignment. Deleting what I don't need breaks the code :(

Can someone help me simplify the code so it will only affect column A?

Also, how do I add the option to include other columns, for example B, C, D, etc.

Lastly, can I have the macro start formatting from A6 downward, B6 downward, C6 downward, etc? That way the header of the chart remains untouched.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will format column A from row 6 down. There were two font colors in there, I removed the first one. To change the column of this code, change the "A"s in the Range() to the column you want to target, e.g. `.Range("B6:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")` etc.

```
Sub PGMNumber()
    ' PGMNumber Macro
        Dim FormatRange As Range
        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            Set FormatRange = .Range("A6:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
        With FormatRange
            With .Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 10
                .Bold = True
                .Color = -10477568
            End With
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Now what if I wanted to make this macro format more than one column at a time? Where do I enter the code for the second column? Specifically column B... Thank you Taylor! @Taylor

Comment: If the columns are all next to each other, change the second "A" in .Range to the last column you need, e.g. `.Range("A6:D" & ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this macro where the two cells in Range() are your top left cell and bottom right cell of the range to format.

```
Sub PGMNumber()
    With Range(Cells(6, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "D"))
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
            .Color = -16776961
            .Bold = True
        End With
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    End With
End Sub
```